# Whining Engine Noise Nissan Qashqai

Tags: engine, transmission, nissan, manual-transmission

**Vehicle**: 2013 Nissan Qashqai

Yesterday driving my Qashqai was a weird experience.

The car starts jerking (as if it were on a hill with low speed/incorrect gear) on the 2nd gear at 2500RPM. I usually change to the 3rd gear at 3500-4000RPM, but have to change gear(up to 3rd) at 2000RPM because of the weird jerk. Someone noticed a whining sound on the 3rd gear. I have lost some "power" in my accelerator pedal.

Can anyone explain what has happened here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Nissan Primera, didn't realise at first but it was only happening when any of the rear lights were on (Sidelights/ Inicators/Brakelight), problem was a common Nissan Primera fault of a bad earth on the rear light assemblies. Just connected an extra wire from each of the rear light assy back plates to the bodywork and problem was solved.